# How to retrieve stock price from Google Finance with 4 decimal places into google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-finance

On google spreadsheet, the price of a stock can be retrieved onto google spreadsheet using the formula `GOOGLEFINANCE("stock_symbol", "price")`. However, price retrieved is only in 2 decimal places. For international stocks, this is not good enough because many of them are penny stocks. 4 decimal places will be much better.

How can one retrieve stock price from Google Finance with 4 decimal places into google spreadsheet? Are there programming tricks to work around this limitation from Google Finance? Will google apps-script be a good choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though this function has been depreciated in GAS.  You might want to look into a way to do it using [Yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api).

Answer (score 6):

```
=round((googlefinance("asx:"&B12,"marketcap")/googlefinance("asx:"&B12,"shares")),4)
```

Where asx is the market outside of NASDAQ and B12 is the ticker.